# Is it possible to define a title attribute by class name?

Tags: html, css, class, tooltip, title

I would like to make all `.note` elements have a specific tooltip.

Is it possible to do this automatically, e.g. in CSS? Just like the `note` class has colors and a font defined, is it possible to bind the tooltip text (the `title` attribute) with that class?

I could make some function that iterates over all `.note` elements and append the `title` attribute if it's not present yet. However, since I don't have to iterate manually for CSS styles, I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this problem as well (e.g. is it possible to define it in CSS?).

Comment: CSS has to do with presentation and style; the title attribute is data, not presentation.

Comment: @cdhowie: infact title is actually a presentation stuff only, not data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not something that's within the scope of CSS. Your best bet is to use some JavaScript or JQuery.

Answer (score 11):

You can't change the attributes of an element using CSS; you could, perhaps, emulate the `title` functionality, though (albeit only clumsily):

```
.note {
    position: relative;
}

.note:after {
    content: "The alternate 'pseudo-title' text for the .note elements.";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    }
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CPSVY/1/).

However using this will still allow the original `title` to show, so I'd suggest removing that attribute with JavaScript (or in a server side language).

Possible JavaScript title-removal method:

```
var notes = document.getElementsByClassName('note');
var notesNum = notes.length;

for (i=0; i<notesNum; i++){
    notes[i].removeAttribute('title');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo (combining the two approaches)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CPSVY/2/).

---

**Edited**, as the OP, from comments (below) doesn't want to change the existing look and feel, to add a JavaScript option to assigning a new title for all elements with the class-name of `note`:

```
var notes = document.getElementsByClassName('note');
var notesNum = notes.length;
var newTextForNotesClass = "This is the new title text for the notes-class-name group.";

for (i=0; i<notesNum; i++){
    notes[i].title = newTextForNotesClass;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CPSVY/3/).

Comment: I'm sorry to say but I prefer the regular tooltip. I'd rather not change the look and feel.

Comment: There's no need to apologise for that! :) Please see the newest edit, which shows a JavaScript solution that (should) meet your needs. :)

Comment: Excellent answer to alter Title attribute with Pure Javascript. If anyone interested in jQuery solution then checkout answer below by @Josh Allen http://stackoverflow.com/a/6975913/5323892

Answer (score 5):

As you asked the question with 'e.g. CSS', I'm presuming you want an answer as to how to use a class to assign a title.  Like the other answers, jQuery or javascript is your best bet.

With jQuery, you can do:

```
tooltip = "Tooltip Text";
$('.note').attr('title', tooltip);
```

Here is a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/RdNvy/

Comment: Excellent answer with jQuery. I wanted to simplify your jsfiddle to see what is bare bone which is needed. And result is awesome, even if no title="" in html tag, even then jquery handles it fine. http://jsfiddle.net/RdNvy/42/  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

CSS is for styling not for carrying out action; you would need JavaScript for that sort of thing. You could use document.getElementsByClassName to get an array that you could for loop through setting those title attributes.

Comment: In fact I'm doing that currently, I was just wondering whether it is possible to define the tooltip text the same way as the font/colors/etc. I'll just continue this way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but try to loot at css "content" property. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp